# No internet after sleeping for awhile

Tags: windows-10, networking

This problem happens since recently. Ethernet, WIFI is connected but no internet after sleeping.

- I tried to replug the ethernet cable but still no internet.
- Tried `ipconfig/release` and then `ipconfig/renew`, but did not solve the problem
- Random Hardware addresses is set to be off.
- did not allow computer to turn off devices(network adapters) to save power (In device manager)
- When there is no internet, I can still see data thru the adapter (in adapter property window)

Here is some information:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
  C:\Users\gabri>ping 8.8.8.8

  Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.
  Request timed out.

  Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
      Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 0, Lost = 2 (100% loss),
  Control-C
  ^C
  C:\Users\gabri>ipconfig/all

  Windows IP Configuration

     Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-86DEIMI
     Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
     Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
     IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
     WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

  Unknown adapter VyprWG:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : WireGuard Tunnel #2
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.4.0.78(Preferred)
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
     DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.4.0.1
     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

  Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-9C-23-43-84-CD
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b96e:d67f:f06d:4416%19(Preferred)
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5(Preferred)
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 31, 2020 4:48:07 AM
     Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, November 1, 2020 3:48:24 PM
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
     DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
     DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 204512291
     DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-8A-92-8C-30-9C-23-43-84-CD
     DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                         8.8.4.4
     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

  Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-12
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c96:6b6e:bc3:25bd%18(Preferred)
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
     DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 537526311
     DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-8A-92-8C-30-9C-23-43-84-CD
     DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                         8.8.4.4
     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-4D-70-7D-5F-FB
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-4D-70-7D-5F-FA
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-4D-70-7D-5F-FA
     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6981:e3c:3858:d63%23(Preferred)
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred)
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 31, 2020 3:48:34 PM
     Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, November 1, 2020 4:15:19 PM
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
     DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
     DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 387730800
     DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-8A-92-8C-30-9C-23-43-84-CD
     DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

  C:\Users\gabri>ipconfig/release

  Windows IP Configuration

  No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 1 while it has its media disconnected.
  No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 2 while it has its media disconnected.

  Unknown adapter VyprWG:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.4.0.78
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b96e:d67f:f06d:4416%19
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c96:6b6e:bc3:25bd%18
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6981:e3c:3858:d63%23
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  C:\Users\gabri>ipconfig/renew

  Windows IP Configuration

  No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 1 while it has its media disconnected.
  No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 2 while it has its media disconnected.

  Unknown adapter VyprWG:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.4.0.78
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b96e:d67f:f06d:4416%19
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

  Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c96:6b6e:bc3:25bd%18
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

     Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6981:e3c:3858:d63%23
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Appreciate for any advice!

Comment: When this behavior happens, which adapter, is actually being used?  You have multiple adapters (WireGuard) for instance that is improperly configured.

Comment: @Ramhound The ethernet adapter is used. vpn droped  when sleeps, and cannot reconnect since there is no internet.

Comment: The ethernet adapter is used or the wireless adapter is used?  Your question specifically mentions you have a wireless adapter (WiFi) problem.

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and when done reset and test:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: The ethernet adapter is used. But it also says no internet on the wireless option. I did try to connect using wireless several times, and it does not work.

Comment: @John ok, I will let the pc sleep for a while to see what happens

Comment: @John I did let it sleep for about 20 mins. after waked it up, it seems like there is internet at the first few moments (I can refresh page). But afterward I cannot connect to internet again.

Comment: Since this happens with both wired and wireless adapters, then at this point, you may wish to do a Windows 10 Repair Install (faster than looking for the needle in the haystack):  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: @John There are 2 options after launching the tool. one is Upgrade this PC now, another is create installation media. I did not see option to repair. Should I Upgrade?

Comment: Use the second option and either (a) run in place if you can or (b) download to a USB key and run Setup.exe on the USB key when Windows 10 is running. That will launch the repair.  I will check my notes.

Comment: @John I ran Setup.exe when Windows 10 is running, but it still ask me to install instead of repair

Comment: If you have a back up of your files, proceed. At some point after the download, it will start and at some ask what you wish to keep. Be sure to select both Apps and Data.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the following link to see if it's helpful to you:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/wi-fi-looses-internet-connection-after-waking-up/420e29b6-a4c6-4b32-8d74-f284e95ead51